# Xcode8 beta adding self.view.layoutIfNeeded() in inputAccessoryView getter causing crash

Tags: layout, inputaccessoryview, swift3, xcode8, ios10

Using Xcode8 Beta my simulator crashes when using an inputAccessoryView and adding the line self.view.layoutIfNeeded() in the getter of the inputAccessoryView override.  It works fine on my devices but this one line causes the simulator to crash everytime

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        return customToolbar
    }
}
```

The following message is displayed in the console:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

If I just remove the line: self.view.layoutIfNeeded() it will work fine on the simulator.  I need that line though or else the collectionView momentarily bounces as the inputAccessoryView keyboard change notification is called.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably fall into new layout loops. See changes in iOS 10 API here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.0/

> Third party apps with custom UIView subclasses using Auto Layout that override layoutSubviews and dirty layout on self before calling super are at risk of triggering a layout feedback loop when they rebuild on iOS 10. When they are correctly sent subsequent layoutSubviews calls they must be sure to stop dirtying layout on self at some point (note that this call was skipped in release prior to iOS 10).